# Creating cascade dropdown depending on the parent dropdown

Tags: dropdown, cascading

I have 7 Dropdown boxes and I want the first one to (Muni) to determine what gets populated in the other dropdown boxes. How would I go about that, do I need to create a list for each of the dropdown boxes?

Below is an example, once a Muni is chosen the other drop down boxes get pre-filled.
Thank you.
[image]

Comment: You could look into spservices for cascading drop downs: http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns

Comment: @BlueBird, you should submit your comment as answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

SPServices javascript library has functionality you want. See [here](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation) for details.

Comment: will this work for 7 columns?

Comment: It works in pairs (parent, child). And you may link them to create longer cascades. But I have not tested it with 7 columns.

Comment: I used this link  http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/758909/Two-Level-Cascading-Drop-Down-in-SharePoint-using

, but how would I go about it if I had 7 dropdown boxes?